# Modify PHP array structure for JSON encoding

Tags: php, arrays

How can I turn an array like this:

```
Array ( [1396076400000] => 1587 [1396162800000] => 1776 [1396249200000] => 2860 )
```

into a JSON array with this format:

```
[[1396076400000,1587],[1396162800000,1776],[1396249200000,2860]]
```

I've tried `json_encode()` but it seems I need to do some work on the array structure before I call that. How can I convert the keys and values of one array into the format that I need?

Comment: foreach array as key => value items = [value, key], json_encode items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function json_custom_encode($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $newArr[] = array($key, $value);
    }
    return json_encode($newArr);
}
```

Try this instead of json_encode.